# Пирамидальные графики

Tags: график, javascript

Доброго времени суток! Посоветуйте библиотеку способную строить пирамидальные графики, вроде того что изображен на картинке:
[image]

Comment: Это обычный график столбиками, просто красиво визуализированный, d3 справится наверное, а прям готовых таких шаблонов наверное нет (если есть то надо искать по ключевым словам того софта что это нагенерил).

Comment: Чтобы сразу, из коробки, строила, не знаю. Но можно сделать на том же [D3](http://d3js.org/), если разобраться: тот же bar chart, вместо прямоугольника рисовать полигон, и поверх – полупрозрачный серый треугольник для теневой стороны. Или как-то иначе «теневые» цвета получать.